# htaccess "silent" redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i am having a bit trouble on my htaccess and maybe you could help me. 
I want to redirect my requests like this:

www.fakedomain.mydomain.com/dev > www.mydomain.com/dev/events/fakedomain.php
The HTTP_HOST would be fakedomain.mydomain.com i guess, but the dev part is important too. My last try was :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /dev/events/%2 [L]
```

This redirect is shown at the top of the browser, something I want to avoid. 
Thank you for your time

Comment: With "at the top of the browser" you mean the address bar? Then mod_rewrite is the completely wrong tool for the job. Look at mod_alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your `DOCROOT/.htaccess` for this, you should use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^(www\.)?(\w+)\.mydomain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^dev/(?!events/)     dev/events/%2.php              [L]
```

The `(?!events/)` bit of the regexp is called a lookahead assertion and this prevents the rule matching `/dev/events/something` and hence prevents a rewrite loop.

If you are using your `DOCROOT/dev/.htaccess` for this, you should use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /dev

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}      ^(www\.)?(\w+)\.mydomain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!events/)      events/%2.php                  [L]
```

The `(?!events/)` bit of the regexp is called a lookahead assertion and this prevents the rule matching `/dev/events/something` and hence prevents a rewrite loop.

Comment: hello TerryE, thanks for the quick reply. The htaccess file is inside the /dev folder, sorry that i didnt point that out

Comment: @DiogoMendonça, I've updated adding the dev/.htaccess version