# htaccess silent redirect with several htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have been working on this problem for the past few days. Tried a number of solutions found on here, none of which ended up working. Here is the issue:

I have two sites, the first being a root-level corporate site, the next being a different site under the same domain.

Site 1: www.domain.com/
Site 2: www.domain.com/site2/

Each of these have their own htaccess file.

Now, we are trying to change the URL of site2, so that it (and all pages under it) read as

www.domain.com/newsitename/

Unfortunately, we cannot change the directory name on the server, so we have to do this via htaccess.

So what I am trying to do is make it so that if you go to:

www.domain.com/newsitename/anypage.php it pulls the content from www.domain.com/site2/anypage.php, but does not change the URL.

So here is the .htaccess I have tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site2/

RewriteRule ^(.*)/site2/(.*)$ $1/newsitename/$2 [L,NC]
```

I have tried placing this on both the www.domain.com/ htaccess and the www.domain.com/site2/ htaccess.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Joe

---

**EDIT**

So it has been pointed out to me below that the code should be on the domain.com/ htaccess, and that there were some issues with my code. I have updated it to the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^newsitename/(.*)$ /site2/$2 [L,NC]
```

This should take any page from www.domain.com/newsitename/ and do a silent redirect to the same page under www.domain.com/site2/. Am I correct on this?

Comment: the .htaccess will have to be in the toplevel dir of the site. You cannot put it into the site2 dir, because requests coming in for `example.com/newsite` would never get into the `/site2` directory to start with, so that subdir .htaccess would never get encountered. it'd be kind of like a business moving to a new building, and putting up a sign at the new building saying "we've moved here" - people going to the old building will see nothing.

Comment: Here is one of the examples that I had already looked at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532313/htaccess-silent-redirect

Comment: Thanks @marc, that clears that stuff up, and makes perfect sense. So as for the code, would I just include the last line in my htaccess on the toplevel directory?

Comment: not sure why you've got (.*)site2, since site2 is already the toplevel dir. just `^newsitename/(.*) /site2/$1` should do. you're mapping the incoming request to the real directory. your version is taking real directory and mapping it to virtual directory.

Comment: and for something as simple as this, you might consider just a simple apache Alias, e.g. `Alias /newsite /path/to/mainsite/site2`. modwrite is a bazooka, you just need a simple redirection.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot access the apache server. We are using a CMS hosted by a private company, that only gives us so much access.

Thanks again by the way - I am not the best with htaccess coding. I know some of the basics, but not much more than that. I have added some modified code above... should the new code work?

Comment: pretty silly that the company won't let you rename a dir, or at least put in an alias...

Comment: What you put in your edit looks correct. Test it out, and if it works, edit it out of the question and post it as an answer instead. This way we (and the system) know the question is answered, and future visitors are mostly interested in the answer, not in the entire question ;-) Also, please note that you are working with what is commonly refered to as *internal rewrites*, not redirects ;-) Redirects are *external*, the things that change the url in the browser.